# Maven - How to replace value in any file in other location?

Tags: maven, mule, mulesoft

I have to replace value in file: test.xml 
This file location is: src/main/app .

It is possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is not good idea to change source of the app on the fly. It is used to build app and, probably, you cannot change it (depened what you need). Also mavne is used to build app based on this source. Not to change the source. Probabaly you need other tools or approaches.

Comment: because in this test.xml file i have set path to the configuration file (test.properties) . It's depends of application name. 
application test1 have test1.xml file in src/main/app and tag <context:property-placeholder location="test1.properties">

Answer (score 0):

Properties could be changed based on the ${app.name}. There is no need to change flow to change property file.

<configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" file="/var/mule/${MULE_ENV}/${app.name}/global.yaml" />

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Properties.html

Comment: problem is that my application is a TEMPLATE for others applications. In maven command i want give name new applications and set this name in .xml file

Comment: What I do is to have one Mule Deployable Archive (just one app) and deploy it to runtime inder different names and so they use different configurations. In short (because of license cost) we have only one test environment whe we run the same app with names app-dev, app-qa, app-prep, app-uat, etc. The same app (not template) which runs for different environments on the same server. Let me know if there is another reason to "build from template" by maven.

Comment: @damianoo applications can be parametrized with properties as Alex explained, so there is no need to actually modify the XML configurations. Modifying the applications at build time doesn't sound like a good practice currently, though it was in fashion many years ago for Java web apps (wars). You can just rename the application deployable file to have it deploy under names. I don't see the need to modify the application unless there is some other issue. Maybe you could clarify why this solution is not acceptable.

Comment: I want replace app.name or project.name only in creating package ... I want use maven command like mvn clean package -Dname=test where name will replace some app places for new app name.
 I set in pom antrun plugin <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${name}.zip/app.xml" toFile="${project.build.directory}/${name}.zip/test.xml"> but this not works