# Maven - What is the path xml file in package in target dir after compile mule application AtnRun Plugin?

Tags: maven, mule, mulesoft

What is the path xml file in package in target dir after compile mule application AtnRun Plugin ? 
I want to copy but i have problem with find path to xml file.
I set `<copy file="${project.build.directory}/${name}.zip/app.xml" toFile="${project.build.directory}/${name}.zip/test.xml">`
but this not works

Error is:
"could not find file ... target/test.zip/app.xml to copy

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is unclear. What is exactly the reason to try to copy an XML to a different name? Is it a Mule configuration? Are you referring to the Maven AntRun plugin? Why are using it?

Comment: because i create new application from application template. I have create new application one mvn command example: mvn clean package -Dname=test

Comment: The answer to that problem as already been given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913293/721855.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Ant copy task can copy files into a zip file. You should use the [zip](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) task for that.

Comment: Ant can copy files into a zip file becacuse it works this:
<copy file="$project.build.outputDirectory/app.properties" fileto="$project.build.outputDirecotry/test.properties">

Comment: hint please ... where global is set app.name and project.name ? where can i replace in pom ?

Comment: ${project.build.finalName} should be the name of the built zip file.

Comment: ${project.build.finalName} for zip file is ok (it works) but still i have a problem with rename .xml file . Is it possible ? Why it is possible to change the zip file name but xml name not ? Maybe it is possible. Please hint.

Comment: intresting is that i haven't problem in rename (copy and delete) with .properties file because properties file is in "classes" directory and refer is $project.build.outputDirecotry/test.properties . With test.xml file is problem that is before "classes" directory. My idea is copy .xml file to new file name and delete old file but i don't know what is correct path to .xml in zip package

Comment: I think it could be in both root and classes. This method gets convoluted because it is trying to hack what Maven does. I still recommend the other method.